# A nice variance inequality

Tags: probability

Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables. Is there a name for the inequality
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X)\leq2\mathrm{Var}(Y)+2E[(X-Y)^2]?
$$

Comment: Where did you find this inequality? Have you tried to prove it? Playing with it, it seems like it could be a result of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality (in either of the forms $(E | XY |)^2 \leq E(X^2)E(Y^2)$ or $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)^2 \leq \mathrm{Var}(X) \mathrm{Var}(Y)$ ).

Comment: If we first assume $E[X]=E[Y]=0$, then the asserted inequality is equivalent to $0\leq E[X^2]+4E[Y^2]-4E[XY]$. By Cauchy-Schwarz, $E[X^2]+4E[Y^2]-4E[XY]\geq E[X^2]+4E[Y^2]-4E[X^2]^{1/2}E[Y^2]^{1/2}=(E[X^2]^{1/2}-2E[Y^2]^{1/2})^2\geq 0$.

Comment: The general case is similar. Here, one uses the special case for $X-E[X]$ and $Y-E[Y]$ and exploits $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\leq \mathrm{Var}(X)^{1/2}\mathrm{Var}(Y)^{1/2}$. Probably, there is no specific name for the inequality.

Comment: A lovely trick. Thanks for sharing. Yes, I expect similar. "A corollary to Cauchy-Schwartz", perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me elaborate the comment in the hope that someone might find this inequality useful.

The inequality is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
0&\leq 2\mathrm{Var}(Y)+E[X^2]+2E[Y^2]+E[X]^2-4E[XY]\\
&=4\mathrm{Var}(Y)+\mathrm{Var}(X)+2(E[X]^2+E[Y]^2)-4E[XY].
\end{align*}
Now by the elementary inequality $2ab\leq a^2+b^2$ and Cauchy-Schwarz, we get
\begin{align*}
4\mathrm{Var}(Y)+\mathrm{Var}(X)+2(E[X]^2+E[Y]^2)-4E[XY]&\geq 4\mathrm{Var}(Y)+\mathrm{Var}(X)-4\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\\
&\geq (2\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(Y)}-\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)})^2\\
&\geq 0.
\end{align*}